# Quantum: Define superposition as linear combination of orthonormal basis

Tags: python-3.x, cmath, qiskit, qubit

I'm testing a code for define a superposition state using a percentage of both basis.

All seems to run well, when the linear percentage is real. But it fails when the percentage is complex parameter.

```
from cmath import sqrt
from typing import List, Tuple

# Standard basis |0>, |1> (Z axis)
zero_qubit = np.matrix([[1.+0.j], [0.+0.j]])
one_qubit = np.matrix([[0.+0.j], [1.+0.j]])
standard_basis: Tuple[np.matrix] = (zero_qubit, one_qubit)


def superposition(
        percentage: float = 100.0,
        basis: Tuple[np.matrix] = (zero_qubit, one_qubit)):
    
    p=sqrt(percentage/100)
    q=sqrt(1-p*p)

    q1 = p*basis[0]+q*basis[1]
    q2 = p*basis[0]-q*basis[1]
    q3 = -p*basis[0]+q*basis[1]
    q4 = -p*basis[0]-q*basis[1]
    return q1, q2, q3, q4

# This works
q1,q2,q3,q4 = superposition(50,standard_basis)

print(q1)
print(q2)
print(q3)
print(q4)

# This generate weird values
q1,q2,q3,q4 = superposition(50j,standard_basis)

print(q1)
print(q2)
print(q3)
print(q4)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question.

The superposition has to consider modules of coeficients (not the coeficient themselves).

So, my current code looks like

```
from math import sqrt
from typing import List, Tuple

# https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_superposition
def superposition(
        alfa: complex = sqrt(.5)+0.j,
        basis: Tuple[np.matrix] = (zero_qubit, one_qubit)):
    
    assert abs(alfa)<=1.0,"Module of assertion coef has to be lower or equal 1"

    if abs(alfa) >= 0.9999999:
        beta: complex = 0.+0.j
    elif abs(alfa) <=0.0000001:
        beta: complex = 1.+0.j
    else:
        alfa_module=abs(alfa)
        beta_module=sqrt(1-alfa_module**2)
        beta: complex=(beta_module/alfa_module)*(alfa.conjugate())
        assert abs(abs(beta)-beta_module)<0.0000001,"Internal error calculating modules"

    q1 = alfa*basis[0]+beta*basis[1]
    q2 = alfa*basis[0]+(-beta)*basis[1]
    q3 = (-alfa)*basis[0]+beta*basis[1]
    q4 = (-alfa)*basis[0]+(-beta)*basis[1]
    print(get_bloch_coordinates(q1))
    print(get_bloch_coordinates(q2))
    print(get_bloch_coordinates(q3))
    print(get_bloch_coordinates(q4))
    return q1, q2, q3, q4
```